# Issue with conflicting SHA key when generating google-services.json

Tags: android, google-signin, developer-console, google-play-services

> An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in
>   another project

I am receiving this error, when trying to setup google services for my app. i need to generate a google-services.json file which is needed for my apps Google SignIn. Now while trying to set it up, i need to specify the SHA key from my release keystore. And this is where it makes me crazy. Like it says, my SHA key is conflicting with an other project. I tried figuring out in which project this could be.. I looked at every project and every credentials if my SHA key is used by them. Unfortunately i dind´find anything.

Now has anyone an idea how to still use this key for my project or how i can find the project where this SHA key is used? I am pleased for any suggestions :P

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160011/the-signing-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-another-android-oauth2), Try to delete the project that is using that SHA1 in console.developers.google.com for the old/incorrect project.

Another solution is to delete the `debug.keystore` and generate a new one.

If you don't know where to find it, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398019/i-cant-find-the-debug-keystore-file) can help you.

To generate a new one, you can create manually by running:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"
```

For more information, you can also check this SO questions:

- [How can I specify location of debug keystore for Android ant debug builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019833/how-can-i-specify-location-of-debug-keystore-for-android-ant-debug-builds)
- [Unable to create Android OAuth2 client ID (duplicate fingerprint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980785/unable-to-create-android-oauth2-client-id-duplicate-fingerprint?rq=1)
- [Google Play Game Services - unable to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580885/google-play-game-services-unable-to-sign-in)
- [An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in another project](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008)

Comment: Well unfortunately it is not an option to delete the project as well as to create an new keystore because my app is already published

Comment: check the additional link if it can help you

Comment: thanks, the last link i red already. It says that i should search in my projects if the sha is used anywhere but i didn´t find any. So i wrote FireBase support with my conflicting sha and package name/project. That was last week and i am still waiting for response :P